# Why is GARCH(1,1) = ARCH(infinity)?

Tags: garch, proof

How do you prove that GARCH(1,1) = ARCH(infinity)? Need some guidance on how to start on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivation is already in [Bollerslev's original paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304407686900631) (see equation (4) and the discussion around it). In general, this equivalence is identical to the equivalence of an ARMA(p, q) and its AR($\infty$) representation if the stationarity and invertibility conditions are met.

Comment: can show the proof. just copy and paste the equation here. I am not able to access the whole paper.

Comment: would appreciate your help...

Comment: @lakesh An ungated copy of the paper is available [here](http://public.econ.duke.edu/~boller/Published_Papers/joe_86.pdf).

Comment: MA(infinite) you mean not AR (infinite)